# Evaluation of Gaussian multivariable integral

Tags: integration, gaussian, multivariable-calculus

In the context of evaluating the propagation of a flattened Gaussian beam, the following integral appears:

\begin{equation}
\int (\mathbf x^T \mathbf F \mathbf x)^n \exp \left [ - \mathbf x^T  \mathbf G \mathbf x + \mathbf x^T \mathbf h \right] d\mathbf x.
\end{equation}
where

- $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf h$ are $2\times 1$ matrices and
- the uppercase matrices $\mathbf F$ and $\mathbf G$ are $2 \times 2$.

A solution to this integral is implicitly used in [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030402604701394), where it is used to find the propagation integral for a flattened Gaussian beam: however the written solution seems to be wrong.
The only thing reported is that the following integral was used:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty x^{2n} \exp(-a^2x^2)\cos(xy)dx = (-1)^n \pi^{1/2} 2^{-(2n+1)} a^{-(2n+1)} \exp \bigg (-\frac{y^2}{4a^2} \bigg ) H_{2n} \bigg (\frac{y}{2a} \bigg )
\end{equation}

The closest integral in the exchange I've been able to find is the one in [this Q&A](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1680107/evaluation-of-multidimensional-integral).

Any hint on how to proceed to solve the first expression will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,

Alex

(Question also posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4464274/evaluation-of-power-times-gaussian-multivariable-integral))

Comment: Please do not cross post questions without at the very least linking between the sites, i.e. link this question to the MSE post.

Comment: I'm confused as to what the question is. Are you looking for an evaluation of the first displayed expression? Or a proof of the second displayed equation? What relation are you saying is wrong, and what makes you think it's wrong?

Comment: Hi @MichaelEngelhardt, I am looking for an evaluation of the first expression; in the referenced paper they mention they use the second expression to solve the first one. The fact that it has a change in integration range and a cosine suggests they did a coordinate transformation to polar coordinates but I haven't been able to carry this out

Comment: I think they did find the right answer but maybe wrote it wrong; a solution to this integral with the appropriate matrices substituted in describes the propagation of a flattened Gaussian beam in 3D; when I plot their expression I don't see that

Comment: in the paper you linked to they only integrate over the first component $x_1$ of $\mathbf{x}=(x_1,x_2)$ --- don't they?

Comment: Hi @CarloBeenakker they integrate over r_1 which has the size of x (2×1)

Comment: For the integral to make sense, you need $G$ to be positive definite. Are you making any assumptions on how $F$ relates to $G$? Are all matrices real valued? Or is $h$ allowed to be complex? Is $h$ completely arbitrary, or is it somehow related to $F$?

Comment: It looks like it should be possible to evaluate it using Wick's theorem.

Comment: Hi @WillieWong, yes G is positive definite. The matrices can be complex but assuming them to be real would be a good start

Comment: Hi @lcv, I know how it can be done using diagonalization if F is a zero matrix, how would Wick's theorem be applied when F is not a zero matrix?

Comment: If $F$ is zero the integral is zero. I am travelling now I can provide an answer in one or two days. Do you need the result for $h\neq0$? Usually one needs these formulas for $h=0$ while a non-zero $h$ is used in intermediate steps in order to obtain the results.

Comment: Hi @lcv, my mistake, if n=0 not F=0. If you can provide the answer or outline to calculate the integral in a few days that'll be great, it is for h not equal to zero

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $\epsilon^{n} /n! $ and summing over $n$, we obtain the generating function
\begin{eqnarray}
M &=& \sum_{n=0}^{\infty } \frac{\epsilon^{n} }{n! }
\int d^2 x\ (\mathbf x^T \mathbf F \mathbf x)^n \exp \left [ - \mathbf x^T  \mathbf G \mathbf x + \mathbf x^T \mathbf h \right] \\
&=& \int d^2 x\ \exp \left [ - \mathbf x^T (\mathbf G - \epsilon \mathbf F) \mathbf x + \mathbf x^T \mathbf h \right]
\end{eqnarray}
Assuming $\mathbf G - \epsilon \mathbf F$ is symmetric, we can diagonalize
$$
O (\mathbf G - \epsilon \mathbf F) O^T = D = \mbox{diag} (d_1 ,d_2 )
$$
with orthogonal $O$ (otherwise, one has to be a bit more careful with the transformation). Substituting $\mathbf y=O\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf k=O\mathbf h$, we have
\begin{eqnarray}
M &=& \int d^2 y\ \exp \left [ - \mathbf y^T D \mathbf y + \mathbf y^T \mathbf k \right] \\
&=& \frac{\pi }{\sqrt{d_1 d_2 } }\exp \left[ \frac{k_1^2 }{4d_1 } +  \frac{k_2^2 }{4d_2 } \right]
\end{eqnarray}
where $d_i $, $k_i $ can be given explicitly in terms of the elements of $\mathbf F $, $\mathbf G$, and $\mathbf h$, as well as $\epsilon $, and the original problem is reduced to obtaining the coefficient of $\epsilon^{n} $ in the expansion of $M$. This is now a purely mechanical calculation, but it is not clear to me whether it reduces to anything reasonably succint without further assumptions on $\mathbf F $, $\mathbf G$, and $\mathbf h$.

Comment: Thank you Michael, following the steps [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/126227/reference-for-multidimensional-gaussian-integral), $M = \pi/2~exp(1/4~h^T P h) ~\sqrt{det(P)}$ where $P = (G - \epsilon F)^{-1}$, how would you start finding the coefficient?

Comment: @Alex - The formula you're quoting there might be off by a factor 2. To obtain the coefficient of $\epsilon^{n} $, just take the $n$-th derivative and then set $\epsilon =0$. You can just have a CAS do it for you - maybe if you try it, you even see a pattern that might suggest a general form for arbitrary $n$, but I'm skeptical unless F,G, and h are such as to make the dependence on $\epsilon $ take some special simplified form.

Comment: Yes my mistake the 2 at the front shouldn't be there. Oh ok so its the coefficients of a Taylor series at $\epsilon=0$, so if I get an expression for the coefficient as a function of n is that the integral? The solution that uses this integral implicitly uses Hermite polynomials, maybe the terms that you get after repeated applications of the product rule can be grouped as a Hermite polynomial

Comment: @Alex Yes, it's just the Taylor series - note that the usual factor $n!$ is already incorporated, so your integral is the $n$-th Taylor coefficient times $n!$, cf. my first expression. Since we're taking derivatives of a Gaussian, the appearance of Hermite polynomials wouldn't be surprising, but I think having independent matrices $F$ and $G$ messes things up so that you don't just get polynomials, but things with ordered products of matrices.

Comment: But the terms $h^T P h = f(\epsilon)$ and $det(P) = g(\epsilon)$ give you a scalar, doing the first derivative gives you $M' = M (f'(\epsilon) + g'(\epsilon)/2/g(\epsilon))$ you can continue that way and all terms are scalar

Comment: @Alex - oh sure, but if you think in terms of expanding your $P$, you'd have products of $F$ and $G$ as opposed to just simple powers of one object, that's why I think you're not simply going to have Hermite polynomials. All that is, alternatively, encoded in the more complicated forms of $f(\epsilon )$ and $g(\epsilon )$ - one can say the same thing several ways.

Comment: Hi Michael, I found a paper that might be useful: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232373026_The_elliptical_Hermite-Gaussian_beam_and_its_propagation_through_paraxial_systems

Comment: In the paper they do a derivation for the propagation of a gauss hermite beam, I think the same procedure can be done for a flattened beam which is the reason I posted this question. The only thing I don't get in the derivation is how the 1d integral is being applied; the variables are still 2 by 1 matrices, and where do the determinants come from?

Comment: @Alex - I'd have to physically go to the library to look at the paper you mention, which I'm not going to do. If you're reading a paper and have a question about some steps, you can try asking that as a question - that's different from the question you asked here. MO questions aren't meant to be a lead-in to an extended trail of discussion - you ask what you want up front and hope for an answer to that. If you have another question, ask it separately.

Comment: Hi Michael, I didn't know you didn't have access. I posted a question regarding this here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424363/applying-1d-integral-to-matrix-integral