# Applying 1D integral to matrix integral

Tags: matrices, integration, determinants, gaussian, multivariable-calculus

In the proof for finding an analytic solution to the propagation of a Hermite-Gaussian beam though a paraxial system given in the paper "[The elliptical Hermite–Gaussian beam and its propagation through paraxial systems](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S003040180201533X)" by Yangjian Cai and Qiang Lin, the following three steps are taken:
$$
\begin{split}
&= -\frac{i}{\lambda} [\det(B)]^{-1/2} \exp(-ikl_0) \exp \bigg[-\frac{ik}{2} r_2^T Q_{e2}^{-1} r_2 \bigg] \\
&\qquad\cdot\iint\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp \Big \{ \big |(B^{-1} A + Q_{e1}^{-1})^{1/2} (Q_{h1})^{1/2} [(ikQ_{h1}^{-1})^{1/2} r_1 \\
&\qquad\qquad - (ikQ_{h1}^{-1})^{1/2} (B^{-1} A + Q_{e1}^{-1})^{-1} B^{-1} r_2] \big|^2 \Big \} H_p \big [|(ikQ_{h1}^{-1})^{1/2} r_1| \big ] dr_1 \\
&= -\frac{i}{\lambda} [\det(B)]^{-1/2} \exp(-ikl_0) \exp \bigg[-\frac{ik}{2} r_2^T Q_{e2}^{-1} r_2 \bigg] [\det(ik Q_{h1}^{-1})]^{-1/2}\\
&\qquad\cdot\iint\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp \Big \{ \big |(B^{-1} A + Q_{e1}^{-1})^{1/2} (Q_{h1})^{1/2} \\ 
&\qquad\qquad[\xi - (ikQ_{h1}^{-1})^{1/2} (B^{-1} A + Q_{e1}^{-1})^{-1} B^{-1} r_2] \big|^2 \Big \} \cdot H_p \big [|\xi| \big ] d\xi \\
&= [\det(B)]^{-1/2} \{ \det[(B^{-1}A+Q_{e1}^{-1}) Q_{h1}] \}^{-1/2} [\det(Q_{h1}^{-1})]^{-1/2} \\
&\qquad[1 - 2/det(B^{-1} A Q_{h1} + Q_{e1}^{-1} Q_{h1})]^{p/2} \bigg[-\frac{ik}{2} r_2^T Q_{e2}^{-1} r_2 \bigg] \\ 
&\qquad\qquad H_p \big \{ [1 - 2/det(B^{-1} A Q_{h1} + Q_{e1}^{-1} Q_{h1})]^{-1/2} | (ik Q_{h1}^{-1})^{1/2} (A + B Q_{e1}^{-1})^{-1} r_2 | \big \}
\end{split}
$$
where
$$
\xi = (ikQ_{h1}^{-1})^{1/2} r_1,
$$
and the following 1D integral is used:
$$
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp \bigg [ -\frac{(a^{-1/2} x - a^{-1/2} b)^2}{2} \bigg ] H_p(x)dx = \sqrt{2 \pi a} (1-2a)^{p/2} H_p \bigg [ \frac{b}{\sqrt{1-2a}} \bigg ] 
$$
and where all uppercase letters are 2 by 2 or 2 by 1 matrices and $|A|$ stands for the modulus of $A$.

I have two questions about the derivation;

- where is $[\det(ik Q_{h1}^{-1})]^{-1/2}$ in the second line coming from? Is it the Jacobian? In that case it should be $[\det(ik Q_{h1})]^{-1/2}$ using $det(\sqrt{A}) = \sqrt{det(A)}$ and $det(A^{-1}) = 1/det(A)$
- How do you go from the second to third lines and end up with $1-2/det()$ terms?

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: Concerning your first question, certainly, the determinant is the Jacobian, and it's fine as written in the derivation: $d^2 \xi = [\det(ikQ_{h1}^{-1} )]^{1/2} d^2 r_1 $, so $d^2 r_1 = [\det(ikQ_{h1}^{-1} )]^{-1/2} d^2 \xi $. Concerning your second question, there seems to be some information missing - there are quantities $\lambda $ and $l_0 $ on one side but not the other side, and I suppose $H_p $ is a Hermite polynomial?

Comment: Hi Michael Right yes the Jacobian is correct, $l_0$ is a propagation distance so a positive scalar and $\lambda$ is the wavelength, both are constants. Yes $H_p$ is a Hermite polynomial. I am going over this proof to see if I can do the same with the flattened beam case, where I could use the following integral: $\int x^n exp[-(x-b)^2]dx=(2i)^{-n} \sqrt{pi} H_n(ib)$. In the flattened beam case you have $()^n$ instead of $H_p()$

Comment: Also I found a paper that writes in a very nice way the derivation for the propagation of a normal Gaussian beam and they use a substitution grouping everything inside the modulus in the exponential in the second line, that might be a more useful substitution. I'm looking into that now

Comment: Coming back to my initial comment - I'm not sure the entire message came across: Your second and third expressions can't be equal as they stand, because there is a dependence on $\lambda $ and $l_0 $ on one side that is not there on the other side. Also, an "exp" seems to be missing, and probably factors $\pi $. In summary, please check your expressions in detail and make sure the equation you're trying to understand is stated correctly. Also, why does your chain of equations start with a "="? Is there another expression at the beginning that's missing?